# How to update a table row with jQUery Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a table that contains two buttons where the user can choose to either approve or decline. I am using jQuery .post() method to update a mysql database with this information and it all works fine. Currently php just echoes back a text response.

Now I want to use ajax to refresh the status field in the table with this new information after the button has been clicked. I'm not sure of the best way to go about this. Should the table be fetched with jQuery .get() from server side or can I just update the status field?

The table

```
**Username  Status              Change Status** 
Anderson    no          (decline button)  (Add button)
julian      yes         (decline button)  (Add button)
```

The jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#myForm2").submit( function(e) { //If add btn pressed
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = this.id;


    var url = "process_ajax6.php";

    var formdata = $(this).serialize();
    formdata += "&btn=btn_add"; // added the btn
    $.post(url, formdata,
        function(data) {

            $("#results").html(data); //Response

        });
});

$("#myForm1").submit( function(e) { //If add btn pressed
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = this.id;
    var url = "process_ajax6.php";

    var formdata = $(this).serialize();
    formdata += "&btn=btn_remove"; // added the btn
    $.post(url, formdata,
        function(data) {

            $("#results").html(data); //Response
        });
  });

});
```

The html table and form

```
echo "<tr>
<td>
<a href=\"profile.php?user_id=".$collab_userid." \" 
 <span class=\"label label-default\" id=\"tag\">".$collab_username."</span></a>
</td>
<td>
".$status."
</td>

<td>
<form id=\"myForm1\" class=\"myForm1\" action=\"\" method=\"post\"   enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"user_id\" value=". $collab_userid." />
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=".$upload_id." />

  <button  type=\"submit\" id=\"btn_remove\" class=\"btn_remove\" name= \"btn_remove\">Remove</button>

</form>
</td>
<td>
<form id=\"myForm2\" class=\"myForm2\" action=\"\" method=\"post\"   enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"user_id\" value=". $collab_userid." />
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=".$upload_id." />

  <button  type=\"submit\" id=\"btn_add\" class=\"btn_add\" name= \"btn_add\">Add</button>

</form>
</td>

</tr>";

}
"</tbody>
</table>";
```

The php

```
 if ($btn=="btn_add") {
$status="yes";

$stmt = $db_conx->prepare('UPDATE tbl_collab SET approved=? WHERE collab_userid=? AND tbl_upload_id=?');
$stmt->bind_param('sss',$status,$user_id,$id);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt){



       echo "<p>user approved</p>";


}
}
    elseif ($btn=="btn_remove"){

$status="no";

$stmt = $db_conx->prepare('UPDATE tbl_collab SET approved=? WHERE collab_userid=? AND tbl_upload_id=?');
$stmt->bind_param('sss',$status,$user_id,$id);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt){

   echo "<h1>user declined</h1>";


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**set an id for your status field in table like this :**

```
<td id='status_1'>
 ".$status."
</td>
```

*when you get php code respone as you say some text you can change just status field html value like this :*

```
$.post(url, formdata,
    function(data) {
        $("#status_1").html('Yes'); //Response
    });
```

});

Comment: This works but is only targeting the first row of the table. If i give each <td id="status"> a unique id eg <id=status_2...id=status_3...) how can I with jquery target the specific row that was clicked?

Comment: its easy just set submit btn id like add_btn1 then set each td element id like status_1 then in onClick function get the number like this : 'var num=this.id.slice(7,this.id.length)' then you can access to td specefic object like this : ' $("#status_"+num).htm()'

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm trying to get my head around it.

Comment: I get it, that great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'd advice to pass back new status from server in response to update query, and use it to update status on frontend in $.post callback.

fastest way to do this - is to add status to the reply as a dom-element:

```
echo "<answer><h1>user declined</h1></answer><status>$status</status>;
```

and in $.post callback access to received data like this:

```
$("#results").html($(data).find('answer').html()); //Response
$("#whatever").html($(data).find('status').html()); //Status
```

of couse you should mark td with status by smth to access it

Comment: I'm working through this answer. The response works echoing back "<status>yes</status>" but I'm having trouble getting it to add to the table in the dom. What do you mean "by smth to access it"? Thanks.

Comment: I mean you should give the `id` to your `td` for example. @farhadamjady wrote example of this in another answer to your question